# ASP.NET MVC routing is not showing the correct view. Returns auth error instead

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC application with `Microsoft.Identity`. I recently created a new controller, `SurveyPeriodController` as follows:

```
[Authorize]
public class SurveyPeriodController : BaseController
{
    private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(SurveyPeriodController));

    private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

    public SurveyPeriodController(ApplicationSignInManager signInManager, ApplicationUserManager userManager, IQueryRunner queryRunner)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        SignInManager = signInManager;
    }

    public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _signInManager = _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _signInManager = value;
        }
    }

    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager = _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }

    // GET: SurveyPeriod
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(Roles = App_Constants.UserRole_Admin)]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        //Removed the logic here. But here it will call to db and fetch some data to be return as the model.
        var model = new List<SurveyPeriodViewModel>() { };
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

I try to navigate to view model using the following code, it returns that I'm not an authorized user to access this page. I tried using `AllowAnonymous` attribute also. However, it's the same error. Also, if I do not have enough permission, I won't be able to see it in the html also as it is checking if I'm an admin.

```
@if (Model.userIsAdmin)
{
    <h1>Navigations</h1>
    <p>
        <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "SurveyPeriod")" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Manage Survey Periods</a>
    </p>
}
```

Currently the view (`index.cshtml`) is as follows.

```
@using Features.SurveyPeriod
@using Humanizer
@model List<SurveyPeriodViewModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Manage Survey Periods";
}

<div class="my-pages" id="survey-periods">
    <p> Test Content</p>
</div>
```

The error I'm receiving is application specific error. However, I think it should be a mistake I did when configure the routing/return view on the controller. Would be appreciate if anyone can provide me a lead to investigate this further.

**UPDATE 1:**

Route config is as follows

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Dashboard", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

And the auth cookie generated through the following code.

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.CreatePerOwinContext(DisDbContext.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
    app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
        ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60),
        LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
        Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
        { 
            OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
        }
    });  
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

If I rename the `.cshtml` and controller's `Index()` method to the same name "SurveyPeriod" - `SurveyPeriod.cshtml` / `SurveyPeriod()` and updating the router to the following, it worked.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("SurveyPeriod", "SurveyPeriod")" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Manage Survey Periods</a>
```

But for the other controllers I have not found any issues like this. Strange!

Comment: What does your RouteConfig look like? Also the code for populating the auth cookie.

Comment: @Alex I have updated the code. TIA

Comment: I don't understand update #2...the request is mapped to name of the controller and it's endpoint, so yes - naming is important.

Comment: @Alex Yes I agree with you, but if I share another endpoint with you `<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Reports")" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Download Reports</a>` is perfectly working. It is belongs to the ReportsController and the method name is Index(). Following the same pattern in SurveyPeriod just not working.